# Installing and downloading data from rbcb package in R

Tags: r

Can you help a begginer in R?

I installed this package here:

[https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/rbcb#market-expectations][1]

I did all the steps to check if I am able to download all the data.

But when I get here:

```
rbcb::get_monthly_market_expectations("IPCA", end_date = "2018-01-31", `$top` = 5)
```

I have this following message:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Why?

Any help?

Comment: restart R and install.packages(c("curl", "httr"))

Comment: @aatrujillob many thanks. But the problem still the same. I still have the same error message. Do you run the code and it work well?

Comment: Weird @Laura I am also having problem with this package.

Comment: @aatrujillob did try to run this code? any problem?

Comment: @DiogoBastos and Laura, yes it worked fine for me. I still think it is a problem with one of the libraries that this package depends on particularly "httr", "curl" or even jsonlite.  You may want to check the namespace file of the package to check other libraries that may be problematic. Restart R, reinstall them and then reinstall the rbcb package as well.